# covert mysql to pdo one script at a time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hi I'm new to PDO but I have been using Mysql and mssql for my last couple projects I was just wondering if you can convert one script at a time or would it be best to convert all of my scripts at once.

I have a couple more questions if someone wouldn't mind pointing me in the right direction.

1) Is there any best practices to converting mysql to PDO?.
2) what would I need to look for when converting to PDO E.g. bugs,common mistakes ... ?
3) to prevent Mysql injection do you have to code in a specific way with PDO or does switching over cancel this out ?

Any help, tutorials or documentation would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Is there any best practices to converting mysql to PDO?.

Don't convert to raw PDO. Convert to ORM/Query Builder/DBAL

> 2) what would I need to look for when converting to PDO E.g. bugs,common mistakes ... ?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

> 3) to prevent Mysql injection do you have to code in a specific way with PDO or does switching over cancel this out ?

There is no magic, you know. It's **prepared statement** that makes your query safe, not a magic chant "PDO". As long as you are able to add **every** variable into query via paceholder - you are safe

Comment: just wondering is there a downside to just writing raw PDO as you put it, or does writing ORM/Query Builder/DBAL give you benefits.?

and just wondering would ORM/Query Builder/DBAL be related to using PDO with websites or is this more of the application side of coding ?

Comment: There is always a downside with using raw API instead of a higher level abstraction. Usually raw API calls require more code to write and require total rewriting if API is going to be changed. However, in case of PDO, it is not that critical as PDO is a semi-DBAL already.